# Why Hamburger won't open when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, performance

Here is code below. I try to write same cod in youtube, but I have problem why my hamburger can't open even it same code. I already pu bootstrap, jquaery, js. data-bs-target actually same with id just put some # to link it. Anyone can help me? Thank you.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
      +0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">

      <title>Frontend Bootcamp</title>
      </head>
      <body>

      <!--Navbar Section-->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark py-3 fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Fronted Bootcamp</a>

        <!--Hamburger Menu button-->
        <button 
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navmenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!--Hamburger link-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#learn" class="nav-link">What You'll Learn</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#question" class="nav-link">Questions</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#instructors" class="nav-link">Instructors</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        </nav>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
    q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a mistake in file url or way you integrated file.

**I have fixed this issue try out code below**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Frontend Bootcamp</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Navbar Section-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark py-3 fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Fronted Bootcamp</a>

        <!--Hamburger Menu button-->
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!--Hamburger link-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#learn" class="nav-link">What You'll Learn</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#question" class="nav-link">Questions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a href="#instructors" class="nav-link">Instructors</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ajwad Aqhari I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you too Gulshan. Aggarwal for helps. It works

Comment: You are always Welcome! @AjwadAqhari

Answer (score 0):

You might have included the wrong `script`. You have to add

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
      +0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Frontend Bootcamp</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!--Navbar Section-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark py-3 fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Fronted Bootcamp</a>

      <!--Hamburger Menu button-->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navmenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!--Hamburger link-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#learn" class="nav-link">What You'll Learn</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#question" class="nav-link">Questions</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#instructors" class="nav-link">Instructors</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>



  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```